# how to query based on key field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

```
"test": {
           "124": {
                    "folders": [
                                {
                                    "unread_count": 0,
                                    "custom": 0,
                                    "id": 2
                                },
                                {
                                    "unread_count": 1,
                                    "custom": 0,
                                    "default_tag": 1,
                                    "id": 3
                                }
                            ],
                            "scans": [
                                {
                                    "folder_id": 3,
                                    "type": "local",
                                    "uuid": "4cf2531f-0d85-3a47-6262-",
                                    "id": 375
                                }
                                ]
                                
                            }
                    }
```

querying to check **if test and 124 fields exist** and **"id": 375 exists or not** which is of **scans** and getting back the same result. if it exists.

I haven't found any material for querying based on field, is there any method.
tried with **must query and exists** returning the empty result.

Comment: can you show your query?

Comment: 1. Please share the document mapping using "GET <index_name>/_mapping" . 
2. There are multiple ids here for scan, folder etc. Which one are you referring.

Please add details to the question

Comment: use a term query and provide the nested path like test.124.scans Check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html#nested-query-notes Also, a lot depends upon the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your data could be far more clean, but you ca do something like this.
If your use case is not simple you'll probably have issue with this.

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    375, 
      "fields": [ "test.*.id"] 
    }
  }
}
```